# Creating a train and a test dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

I have actually a directory `RealPhotos` containing 17000 `jpg` photos. I would be interested in creating a train dataloader and a test dataloader

```
ls RealPhotos/
2007_000027.jpg  2008_007119.jpg  2010_001501.jpg  2011_002987.jpg
2007_000032.jpg  2008_007120.jpg  2010_001502.jpg  2011_002988.jpg
2007_000033.jpg  2008_007123.jpg  2010_001503.jpg  2011_002992.jpg
2007_000039.jpg  2008_007124.jpg  2010_001505.jpg  2011_002993.jpg
2007_000042.jpg  2008_007129.jpg  2010_001511.jpg  2011_002994.jpg
2007_000061.jpg  2008_007130.jpg  2010_001514.jpg  2011_002996.jpg
2007_000063.jpg  2008_007131.jpg  2010_001515.jpg  2011_002997.jpg
2007_000068.jpg  2008_007133.jpg  2010_001516.jpg  2011_002999.jpg
2007_000121.jpg  2008_007134.jpg  2010_001518.jpg  2011_003002.jpg
2007_000123.jpg  2008_007138.jpg  2010_001520.jpg  2011_003003.jpg
...
```

I know I can subclassing TensorDataset to make it compatible with unlabeled data with

```python
class UnlabeledTensorDataset(TensorDataset):
    """Dataset wrapping unlabeled data tensors.
    
    Each sample will be retrieved by indexing tensors along the first
    dimension.
    
    Arguments:
        data_tensor (Tensor): contains sample data.
    """
    def __init__(self, data_tensor):
        self.data_tensor = data_tensor
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data_tensor[index]
```

And something along these lines for training the autoencoder

```python
X_train     = rnd.random((300,100))
train       = UnlabeledTensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train).float())
train_loader= data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=1)

for epoch in range(50):
    for batch in train_loader:
        data = Variable(batch)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, data)
```

Comment: Do you want `ArtificialPhotos` to be in the train set and `RealPhotos` to be in the test set?

Comment: @Ivan Sorry, during the time you built an answer I modify my question. Don't remove what you have just written in your answer, but edit it instead.

Comment: So basically you want to split your data and create two loaders?

Comment: Yes, a portion of the photos will be use to test the autoencoder and the other portion will be used to train the autoencoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to define a Dataset ([`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#map-style-datasets)) then you can use DataLoader on it. There is no difference between your train and test dataset, you can define a generic dataset that will look into a particular directory and map each index to a unique file.

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.files = os.listdir(directory)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(self.files[index]).convert('RGB')
        return T.ToTensor()(img)
```

Where `T` refers to [`torchvision.transform`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html) and Image is imported from [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

You can then instanciate a dataset with

```
data_set = MyDataset('./RealPhotos')
```

From there you can use [`torch.utils.data.random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) to perform the split:

```
train_len = int(len(data_set)*0.7)      
train_set, test_set = random_split(data_set, [train_len, len(data_set)-train_len])
```

Then use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` as you did:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=16, shuffle=False)
```